# Problem of visualizing a Python written Boxplot in R

Tags: python, r, python-3.x, boxplot

I want to visualize some data in Boxplot. I have the code written in Python but I want to rewrite it in R.

This is the code in Python :

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

d = df.to_numpy()
f = [d[m] for d, m in zip(d.T, ~np.isnan(d).T)]

ax.boxplot(f)
ax.set_ylim([0, 150])
ax.set_ylabel('IRE binding activity (%)', fontsize=14)
ax.set_xticklabels(['NF', 'F'])
ax.tick_params(axis='x', labelsize=14, labelrotation=45)
ax.tick_params(axis='y', labelsize=14)

glue('fig1', fig, display=False)
```

This is what I've tried in R:

```
na_if(d, df)
f <- [d[m] for d, m in zip(d.T, ~np.isnan(d).T)]
boxplot(f)
boxplot(NF ~ F, data = f, col = "lightgray", varwidth = TRUE, 
        main = "IRE binding activity for non-failing (NF) and failing (F) hearts.",
        ylab = "IRE binding activity (%)",xlab = "['NF', 'F']")
fivenum(f)
```

And this my data code included a t-test function:

```
labels <- list('non-failing heart (NF)', 'failing heart (F)')

data <- list(c(99, 52), c(96, 40), c(100, 38), c(105, 18), 
             c(NA_integer_, 11), c(NA_integer_, 5), c(NA_integer_, 42), 
             c(NA_integer_, 55), c(NA_integer_, 53), c(NA_integer_, 39),
             c(NA_integer_, 42), c(NA_integer_, 50))

df <- setNames(do.call(rbind.data.frame, 
                       lapply(data, function(d) data.frame(d[1], d[2]))),
              labels)    
df
                           
                           
results <- t.test(df[['non-failing heart (NF)']], df[['failing heart (F)']])

results
                           
results$statistic
results$estimate
results$p.value
                           
ceiling(results$p.value * 1000.0)/ 1000.0
```

Comment: Without a sample of data, I can't put code together but have you looked at using `ggplot`? http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/ggplot2-box-plot-quick-start-guide-r-software-and-data-visualization

Comment: We do not have your data. And technically I do not understand what you are trying to accomplish. If it is a matter of running the python script in R, just use `reticulate::source_python(your_python_file)`

Comment: @NColl sorry guys, I forget to put the data, I just edit it my code, you can take a look at it

Comment: @Onyambu I should rewrite it R and not use reticulate

Comment: R does not have list comprehensions.  `f <- Filter(Negate(is.na), d)` is the first code you should have

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've successed to rewrite the code in R and I want to share the solution with you :

```
boxplot(df[1:2],
        data=df,
        main="box plot",
        ylab="Degree Fahrenheit",
        col="orange",
        border="brown",
        ylim = c(0, 120)
)
```